# How can I restore Master Boot Record in Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: boot, hard-drive

Old computer running Ubuntu 14.10 died so I purchased a new machine and had the HDD (500GB) from the old machine swapped into the new machine along with a new 1TB drive.  Everything fired up OK so I updated all the software and then upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04.  Tested and everything seemed to be fine programs worked etc.  Then I attempted to format the new drive as one partition but the system defaulted to two.  However I had changed the CMOS to boot from blank drive first, but that didn't make any difference, it still booted from the original drive so I changed the CMOS back to boot from the original drive and on reboot got a "MBR not found - press ctrl, alt, del to restart" error.  tried different devices as the boot device with no joy until I put a CD in the optical drive and from there I am able to boot from the original drive.  How can I restore the MBR to this drive without reinstalling the OS?

I seem to have solved the issue;  I put the Ubuntu 14.04.2LTS DVD in the optical drive and let it boot to the install screen, then told it I didn't want to install and closed down.  Removed the DVD from the drive and it restarted correctly.  Tried a few shutdowns and restarts just to make sure - it now works just as it should